# Wrong exception being thrown

Tags: java, exception

I'm passing in a string to this method. The string is "44". I then parse it into an int and do an if statement to see if it's between 1 and 12. It then goes to the else statement where I have - throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal month number here: " + inSetString);

For some reason, that doesn't get thrown and it goes down to the next exception and that one is thrown - throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month name string: " + inSetString);

Why does it throw the second exception statement but not the first? It DOES go to the else statement. I've tested that by using - System.out.println("except" + inSetString);

Here's my code:

```
 public void setMonthName(String inSetString)    
 {
         int i = 0;
         monthNumber = -1;

         try
         {
            System.out.println("first" + inSetString);
            i = Integer.parseInt(inSetString);
            System.out.println("next" + inSetString);
            if (i >= 1 && i <= 12)
            {
               monthNumber = i;
            }
            else
            {
                   System.out.println("except" + inSetString);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal month number here: " + inSetString);
            }
         }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {       

            }

      // if it gets to here we know it's a string
         for (int index = 0; index < monthNames.length; index++)
         {
            if (monthNames[index].equalsIgnoreCase(inSetString))
            {
               monthNumber = index;
            }
         }
         if (monthNumber == -1)
         {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month name string: " + inSetString);
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception is thrown, but then you have a catch block that doesn't do anything and allows the execution to continue. You then reach the other exception and that one crashes the program.

Try adding some logging (or `e.printStackTrace()`) in your catch block, you'll see what happens.

Also, try using your IDE's debugger instead of adding print statements. You'll have a better understanding of your program's execution.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. How do I get it to throw the first IllegalArgumentException that's inside the else statement?

Comment: @KebinKeeler You already throw it ! But you catch it and do nothing about it. So either remove the `try-catch` and handle the error somewhere else (where the method is called) or actually do something in your `catch` block (e.g. log and throw again). It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem I can't figure out is that if I add a throw new IllegalArgumentException to the catch block and pass in "Saturday" it throws the Illegal month number here message instead of Invalid month name string. This is because "Saturday" is getting an exception when I try to use the Integer.parseInt(). "Saturday" doesn't make it's way down to the IllegalArgumentException. I'm trying to account for any input that's not between 1 to 12 or a day of the month.

Comment: "or a day of the month" - I mean a name of a month. monthNames[] is an array that holds all of the names of the months. If I add the IllegalArgumentException to the catch, it doesn't allow legal input such as "January"

Comment: Why don't you simply use overloads? `setMonthName(int monthNumber)` and `setMonthName(string monthName)` and handle both cases separately ? It would be a much better design and it will make your life easier to handle your problem.

Comment: I did do that, actually. The one I posted was just for strings, because you can enter in a number as a string or an integer. I found the error in my code. I needed to move the bottom portion into the catch block and add another if statement to it.